# How to keep a dropdown displayed after showing with hover event?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, mouseevent, dropdown

I have a header composed of navigation links to other websites, some of these links are shown through drop-down menus.
With the event hover I have added an animation and style to see what you are on at every moment and that, in case of a drop-down, shows you all the options.
The thing is that I don't know how to keep the drop-down menu displayed to select any of the links and that it disappears in case of @mouseleave.
I have tried to take the event @mouseleave to the dropdown itself but it doesn't work.
If someone can make me see my mistake.
Thanks in advance for your time and help.
I leave you a link with a sample which I have it working now

https://codepen.io/carlosurra/pen/YzqXjdP

this is my template

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light header">
                 
                  
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav menu">
                      
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">PERSONAL INFO</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link menu-link-toggle" @mouseover="animalList = true" @mouseleave="animalList = false" >PERSONAL FORM</a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu' v-if="animalList">
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>DATA</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>FORM DATA</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >AUTOCOMPLETE</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class='menu-link menu-link-toggle' @mouseover="serviceList = true" @mouseleave="serviceList = false">SERVICES</a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu' v-if="serviceList">
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >LA CRÉMATION PRIVÉE</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' href="https://www.esthima.fr/incineration-reference">PERSONAL S</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>COMPANY S</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >FULL S INFO</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link ">SHOP</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item active">
                        <router-link class="nav-link" to="/devis">TARIFS ET DEVIS </router-link>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class='menu-link menu-link-toggle' @mouseover="contactList = true" @mouseleave="contactList = false">CONTACT</a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu' v-if="contactList">
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>MAIL</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
                            <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >PHONE</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li> 
                    </ul>
                  </div>
              </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my css

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.menu-link-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em 1.25em 0.5em 0.75em;
  background-color: white;
  width: max-content;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 24px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.21);
}

.dropdown-menu-item {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu-link {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.head {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.head:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 35%;
  background: red;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: .25s linear;
}

.head:hover:before,
.head:focus:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);

}

.added {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the mouseover and mouseleave events on the `<li>` element that contains both the link and the dropdown.

```
<li class="nav-item" @mouseover="animalList = true" @mouseleave="animalList = false">
  <a class="nav-link menu-link-toggle">PERSONAL FORM</a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu' v-if="animalList">
    <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>

      <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>DATA</a>
    </li>
    <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
      <a class='dropdown-menu-link'>FORM DATA</a>
    </li>
    <li class='dropdown-menu-item'>
      <a class='dropdown-menu-link' >AUTOCOMPLETE</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```